# add associations to exisiting models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations

I'm wondering how I can add associations to my models. Suppose, I generate two models

```
rails generate model User
rails generate model Car
```

Now I want to add an associations so that the models acquire the form

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The question is: how to apply this modification by migrations in order to obtain cars_users table in the database? I'm planning to use that table in my code.

Comment: you have no need for a `cars_users` table since you don't have a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`belongs_to` association expect an `association_id` column in its corresponding table.  Since cars belongs_to user, the cars table should have a `user_id` column.  This can be accomplished 2 ways.

first, you can generate the column when you create the model

```
rails g model car user_id:references
```

or just add the user_id after you create the model like Richard Brown's answer.  Be careful that if you use `integer` instead of `references`, you'd have to create the index yourself.

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_cars user_id:integer
```

then in the generated migration, add

```
add_index :cars, :user_id
```

UPDATE:

As Joseph has mentioned in the comments, the need to add the index manually has already been addressed in the current version of Rails.  I think it was introduced in Rails 4.  You can read more of it in the [official Rails guide for migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration).  The gist of it is running the following generator

```
bin/rails g migration add_user_to_cars user:references
```

will create a migration with a line similar to

```
add_reference :cars, :user, index: true
```

This will add a `user_id` column to the cars table and it will also mark that column to be indexed.

Comment: just curiosity: what if between the models there were has_and_belongs_to_many association. Who would be then responsible for creation of cars_users table? Me, Ruby on Rails or somebody else?

Comment: you. habtm join tables don't need a class but still need the table and you need to create a migration for that :)

Comment: Instead of doing this in two steps, you can add references after model creation like so: `rails g migration addUserReferencesToCars user:references`. This takes care of adding `user_id` to `cars` and making it an index in one shot.

Answer (score 21):

Following @jvnill's explanation in **rails 4** (and maybe in rails 3.2 too) you can do it like this too (avoiding the id parts and remembering the exact convetions):

```
rails g migration AddUserToCar user:references
```

Which will create the following migration, taking care of both adding the column and index with all correct conventions:

```
class AddUserToCar < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :cars, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

At the end as always run the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

View your `schema.rb` to view the new index and user_id column.

Answer (score 10):

Generate a migration to create the association:

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToCars user_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Migration file:

```
class Createuser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.varchar(255) :model
      t.varchar(255) :color
    end
  end
end
```