# How to add relation beeween two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these models on Rails :

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :tweets
end
```

but on bd there isn't a relationship between these models.
Which migration i need to do for add user_id into tweet table?

Comment: twees must have user_id column

Comment: rails g migration add_user_id_to_tweets user_id:integer

Comment: Looks like a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385087/add-associations-to-exisiting-models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the **migration** to run:

```
change_table :tweets do |t|
  t.references :user
end
```

This will **add a column** named `user_id` to the `tweets` table. (Don't forget to run a `rake db:migrate` to update the Database!)

[**Documentation of `change_table`** (ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements) - APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `user_id` into your `Tweet` model then in your model you can do:

run `rails g migration add_user_id_to_tweets user_id:integer`

Which will give you the following output

```
  class AddUserIdToTweet < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tweets, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: As I know there is no need to add foreign key as this is used by default, you set foreign key if you want to tie this table using an attribute different to user_id

Comment: @rmagnum2002 - Check this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables

Comment: @rmagnum2002 Pretty sure the child needs a foreign_key, else I've been doing Rails associations / SQL completely wrong for the past couple of years ;). Also I'd change the order of code snippets there to save confusion, the migration file gets auto-generated with that last command.

Comment: `add_column :tweets` (plural needed here)

Comment: foreign_key ?? never used it in my apps, only if I need to refer to another column, like in case instead user_id I'll use person_id

Comment: @rmagnum2002 Sorry that statement might have been confusing, I should have said 'Pretty sure the child needs a foreign key'. If you don't have a foreign key in the child table SQL won't know what primary key to reference for the parent.

Comment: @Cyle I was talking about the first answer where David added has_many: tweets, foreign_key: user_id and I was saying there is no need to use it as long as you have user_id in table. Never said that we don't need user_id in database

Comment: @rmagnum2002 Oh crap, I see what you mean. Sorry I didn't see David's first edit. :P