# Add association to existing model using a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations

Say you have these two models

```
rails generate model User
rails generate model Car
```

Now I want to add an associations so that the models acquire the form

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
en
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :driver, foreign_key: "driver_id", class_name: "User"
end
```

What will my migrations look like to add the proper column to car? Should it be a column named driver_id or user_id?

This is a variation on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385087/add-associations-to-exisiting-models).

Comment: You can eventually use `belongs_to :driver, class_name: 'User'` and just create a column `driver_id`

Comment: It should be the `driver_id` as the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use different [`foriegn_keys`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) in your associations, you have to remember these associations will only use the `foreign_key` you provide

--

This means if you're looking to use this association:

```
belongs_to :driver, foreign_key: "driver_id", class_name: "User"
```

The migration / table will look like this:

```
add_column :cars, :driver_id, :integer
```

Comment: Don't you mean add_column :cars, :driver_id, :integer ?