# association between two model in rails , controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I can not find the issue with my association, but continuously getting error related to the association. I added has_many to Schools and belongs_to to members.

```
 class CreateMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
   create_table :members do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :email
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

end

```
 class CreateSchools < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :schools do |t|
  t.string :name

  t.timestamps
end
```

end
  end

```
 class AddSchoolRefToMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
  add_reference :members, :school, foreign_key: true
end
```

end

Controller:

```
class MembersController < ActionController::Base
 before_action :set_school
def index
 @members = Member.all
end
def new
  @member = Member.new
end

def create
 @member = Member.new(member_params)
 @member.school = @school
 @member.save
 redirect_to members_path
end


private

def set_school
 @school = School.find(params[:school])

end

def member_params
  params.require(:member).permit(:name, :email,:school)
end
```

end

Comment: What kind of error exactly? Can you show a log?

Comment: This SO article on [Adding Assoiations to Existing Models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385087/add-associations-to-exisiting-models).  Might be worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the @school itself you should assign the id of that school:

```
def create
 @member = Member.new(member_params)
 @member.school = @school.id      # here it is @school.id 
 @member.save
 redirect_to members_path
end
```

The associations work with IDs not Arrays.
@school return the school record completely you just need the id to create the association.

Comment: This is wrong, try this `@member.school = @school` in your console, you can.

Comment: As you can read in the rails docs, the proper way of working with associations is through ids: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html I don't work without ids.

Comment: Edit: I just tried it in the console and it doesn't work. When I assign a user to a post.user_id, it returns nil and doesn't save. How did it work for you ?

Comment: What nil? What you have tried

Here is example

`a1 = Table1.new(a: 'test', b: 'test')
a1.user = User.find(10)
a1.save!`

Comment: The problem is that a1.user is of type reference and therefore has to be an ID.

Comment: We can do using both way, but assign `id` is not necessary.

`a1.user = User.find(10).id` or `a1.user = User.find(10)`

Comment: Well I tried it in my project and I can't. So something must be different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137110/discussion-between-ashvin-and-alexander-luna).

Comment: I can not chat in there yet due to the reputation, but this still does not work. This is in the new.html.erb:

   <%= simple_form_for [@school, @member] do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :name %>
   <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.select :school, options_for_select(School.all.each{|s|[s.name, s.id   ]}) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>


and I change the ones above, but still get an error message: param is missing or the value is empty: member

Comment: sorry, the error message is : Couldn't find School with 'id'=

Comment: How did you set up the association in your models ?